# Can someone assist this code pertaining Discord.js?

Tags: javascript

In the code that is shown below is supposed to find a user(s) within the servers that the bot is in but it seems not to be doing its job.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
    if (!message.member.hasPermission(`BAN_MEMBERS`)) return;
    message.delete().catch(O_o => { });
    let noUser = await message.channel.send(`No match has been found for that user.`);
    let member = client.users.cache.get(args[0]);
    if (!member) {
        message.channel.send(`That ID isnt a user of ${client.user.username}`);
        noUser.delete().catch(O_o => { });
        return;
    }
    let guild = client.guilds.cache.map(m => {
        const search = m.members.cache.get(args[0]);
        if (search) {
            message.channel.send(`**Server Info:** ${m.name} | | ${m.id} **Owner:** ${m.owner.user.username} | | ${m.owner.user.id}\n**User Info:** ${member.username} | | ${member.id}`);
            noUser.delete().catch(O_o => { });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What precisely does *"seems not to be doing its job"* mean? Give a [mre].

Comment: ok so when the code is inside of the software and its running and it is used

it gives this

``No match has been found for that user``

when the user is in the server or multiple servers.